# Change GWT application behavior between deployed and debug environment

Tags: gwt, debugging

I would like to have my GWT application use different constants when debugging or developing vs when deployed.   What is the right way to do this?   My web searches turn up a lot of pages about debugging GWT applications, which isn't what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a job for [deferred binding](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html#replacement)! ;)
It would look something like this (put this in your module XML file, I haven't actually tested it, but you should get the gist of it):

```
  <define-property name="debug" values="true,false" />
  <set-property name="debug" value="true" />

  <replace-with class="package.Constants">
    <when-type-is class="package.Constants"/>
  </replace-with>

  <replace-with class="package.ConstantsDebug">
    <when-type-is class="package.Constants" />
    <when-property-is name="debug" value="true"/>
  </replace-with>
```

See [the docs](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModuleXml) for more information on available parameters, rules and whatnot.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted.  Thanks.

Comment: Just to add, GWT already has a debug flag - `gwt.enableDebugId` that controls the `ensureDebugId()` method. You can use that as a reference implementation, or better - can reuse the same flag.